# kendo bar chart colors of categories

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

Please see here: http://jsbin.com/teveza/edit?html,output

Basically I'm trying to have two horisontal bars for comparison. I want them to have a categoryAxis title and have different colors. And I cannot get both.

So far the closest I can get is this:

```
{
  seriesColors: ["red", "green"],  
  "seriesDefaults": {
    "type": "bar"
  },
  series: [
    { data: [2,3] },
  ],  
  categoryAxis:{
    categories:["Red Category","Green Category"],
    lables:{
      visible:true, }
  }


}
```

So.... any pointers on how to do that will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series object has a property called colorField that can be used for this:
http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.colorField

You can use it in one of the following 2 ways:

> Updated **[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/gupila/1/edit?html,output)**

```
$("#chart1").kendoChart({
  theme: "flat",
  dataSource: {
    data:[
    {key: "Red Category", value: "2", usercolor: "red"},
    {key: "Green Category", value: "3", usercolor: "green"},
  ]},
  seriesDefaults: {
    type: "bar", 
  },
  series: [{ 
      field: "value",
      categoryField: "key",
      colorField: "usercolor",
  }],  
});

$("#chart2").kendoChart({
  theme: "flat",
  seriesDefaults: {
    type: "bar", 
  },
  series: [{ 
      field: "value",
      colorField: "usercolor",
      data: [
        {value: "2", usercolor: "red"},
        {value: "3", usercolor: "green"},
      ],
  }],  
  categoryAxis:{
    categories:["Red Category", "Green Category"],
  }
});
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks for helping me on this one also. I really must learn to understand the kendo api reference better :-)