# kendo chart series legend in top on two lines

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have an implementation of a chart where the legend must be in top for screen size reasons. My customer complains that it is hard to see the (in this case) two series titles.

Currently it shows like this:

[] series title 1  [] series title 2

I want:

[] series title 1
[] series title 2

setting legend.position = "right" shows them like I want, but on the side, so it must be set to "top"

Any way to achieve this?

Look here http://plnkr.co/edit/BVPb4AivJuks5VGr6FGz?p=preview

Chart is configured like this:

```
{
  "chartArea": {
    "font": "14px/1.714 \"roboto\", \"Arial\", \"Helvetica\", sans-serif",
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 333.3333333333333,
    "background": "",
    "border": {
      "color": ""
    }
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "",
    "font": "14px/1.714 \"roboto\", \"Arial\", \"Helvetica\", sans-serif"
  },
  "legend": {
    "position": "top"
  },
  "seriesDefaults": {
    "markers": {
      "visible": false
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "type": "column",
      "name": "03-02-2016",
      "data": [
        0.110845970287301,
        0.0914614304545012,
        0.0828538550058511,
        0.0828538550056237,
        0.0897167892449033,
        0.178615728107161,
        0.178615728107161,
        0.178615728107161,
        0.178615728107161,
        0.0727362937236649,
        0,
        0
      ],
      "color": "#8f9b49"
    },
    {
      "type": "line",
      "name": "02-02-2016 (perioden før!)",
      "data": [
        0.110709412367669,
        0.0911219388724476,
        0.0911219388722202,
        0.0911219388724476,
        0.0911219388722202,
        0.0235651458583561,
        0.140159626241029,
        0.140159626241029,
        0.140159626241029,
        0.075608331711237,
        0.899526564965754,
        0.899526564965754,
        0.899526564965754,
        0.687138348237795,
        0.431259248819742,
        0.431259248819742,
        0.431259248819515,
        0.400167587908072,
        0.325565217391159,
        0.325565217391386,
        0.325565217391159,
        0.260910866318909,
        0.110845970287073,
        0.110845970287073
      ],
      "color": "#bdc779",
      "border": {
        "width": 1,
        "color": "#dddddd"
      }
    }
  ],
  "valueAxis": {
    "plotBands": [],
    "title": {
      "text": "kWh",
      "background": "none",
      "font": "14px/1.714 \"roboto\", \"Arial\", \"Helvetica\", sans-serif"
    },
    "labels": {
      "format": "{0}",
      "font": "12px/1.714 \"roboto\", \"Arial\", \"Helvetica\", sans-serif"
    },
    "line": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "axisCrossingValue": 0
  },
  "categoryAxis": {
    "majorGridLines": {
      "width": 0
    },
    "title": {
      "text": "Time",
      "background": "none",
      "font": "14px/1.714 \"roboto\", \"Arial\", \"Helvetica\", sans-serif"
    },
    "categories": [
      "00",
      "01",
      "02",
      "03",
      "04",
      "05",
      "06",
      "07",
      "08",
      "09",
      "10",
      "11",
      "12",
      "13",
      "14",
      "15",
      "16",
      "17",
      "18",
      "19",
      "20",
      "21",
      "22",
      "23"
    ],
    "line": {
      "visible": false
    },
    "labels": {
      "padding": {
        "top": 4
      },
      "font": "12px/1.714 \"roboto\", \"Arial\", \"Helvetica\", sans-serif"
    }
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "visible": true,
    "format": "{0}m2",
    "template": "#= series.name # #= category #: #= value #"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's supposed to see something in the external example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the legend **[orientation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-legend.orientation)** to vertical and then set the **[height](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-legend.height)** as needed:

```
  legend: {
    position: "top",
    orientation: "vertical",
    height: 50    
  },
```

Comment: Just perfect. Its not that the good people at Telerik don't document their stuff.... but boy....with so many settings its hard to find the right one. Thanks

Comment: Since you know your way around Kendo..... would you happen to have a good answer to this one also? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269126/kendo-bar-chart-colors-of-categories